# Unable to set cuSparse environment variable in Python application

Tags: python, environment-variables

I'm trying to use [pyculib](http://pyculib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the first time. I got `pyculib` by doing:

```
pip install PyCulib
```

But when I try a simple import statement like:

```
import pyculib
```

I get the error message:

```
Exception: Cannot open library for cusparse: library cusparse not found
```

Googling a little, I think that it is because the cuSPARSE library is not linked to my Python application. Consequently, I decided to try linking it by setting an environment variable:

```
import os
os.environ['PYCULIB_CUSPARSE']='/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcusparse.so'
```

To make sure that it has been set properly, I checked two things:

1. Making sure that the path to the cusparse library is correct

I used the command `locate cusparse` to find the path.

2. Making sure that the variable has been set

I did a `print(os.environ.get('PYCULIB_CUSPARSE'))` right after setting the variable in the same application to check that the variable has indeed been set.

Despite  all these, when I tried to do `import pyculib` again (in the same application), the same error message appears, warning that the library cusparse is not found. Any idea what is going on, and how I can do proper linking in my Python application?

P/S I have previously managed to set an environment variable (successfully) for Numba's `libnvvm` by doing:

```
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM']='/usr/local/cuda-9.0/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so'
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE']='/usr/local/cuda-9.0/nvvm/libdevice/'
```

but it seems like the same trick is not working here.

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA says to set CUDA/bin in the NUMBAPRO_CUDALIB variable

[nvidia devtalk](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1036884/gpu-accelerated-libraries/cannot-find-cusparse-library-in-pyculib-on-anaconda3/)

it's for me

```
import os
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_CUDALIB']='C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.1\\bin'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try

```
conda install pyculib
```

This is the approach recommended by Pyculib themselves:

```
http://pyculib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-pyculib
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention it, but because of some restrictions I only have access to `pip` and not `conda` (and `pip install conda` doesn't give me the `conda` I need :P Besides, why doesn't `pip` work?

Comment: I don't know why Pip doesn't work.  I had exactly the same problem as you ('library cusparse not found') and solved it simply by using Conda.  Good luck with Pip.